# Getting location coordinates from device like iPhone in Java (not based on IP more like GPS or cell signal)

Tags: java, coordinates, smartphone

How can one get more accurate location coordinates from mobile device (smarthphone, iPhone, BlackBerry ...) other than from IP address. For example by using GPS query from smartphone API. And how would one go about integrating with Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what you're asking.

If you mean "How can one retrieve GPS coordinates using Java in a native application on a smartphone?", then that answer will differ for every smartphone platform, and there is no answer for iPhones because iPhones do not run Java.

If you mean "How can one retrieve GPS coordinates in a web application using Java on the backend?", then you can use the Geolocation API in HTML5, assuming the browser supports it (as far as I know, Mobile Safari and the browser in Android support this. I don't know about Blackberry, and would assume that it does not). See [here](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html).

Comment: There a small javascript library that bridges the gap between the W3C Geolocation API and proprietary APIs like Blackberry - http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/